# ImageView scaleType to crop right and bottom?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView that is 100px x 50px. I want to give it a bitmap that is 300px x 200px in size.

How can I have the ImageView crop the right and bottom sides of the bitmap?

All the scaleType options seem to crop by placing the bitmap in the center of the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:scaleType="matrix"` in XML of the ImageView and set the Matrix to position the image at 0,0 using `ImageView#setImageMatrix` programmatically:

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myIV"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    ... />
```

java:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myIV)).setImageMatrix(new Matrix());
                                                    //android.graphics.Matrix
```

The empty constructor creates the identity matrix. The matrix is applied using the left-top corner of the view as the origin. Before applying the matrix the left-top corner of the image is put at the origin.

That means it starts with the image aligned to the left and top of the view which is what the question asked for, so the answer uses the identity matrix to leave it there.

Comment: Can you guys post an example of code that does this please?